# URL Rewrite with htaccess and PHP

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have a URL: search/?word=asdf and want to redirect to: search/word/asdf/ and running internally:  ?cmd=search&word=asdf

This so you can get the PHP $ _GET ['cmd'] and $ _GET ['word'].

How to do it in htaccess?

**EDIT:**

My .htaccess now is:

```
RewriteRule search(.*) %{HTTP_REFERER}cmd/search$1
RewriteRule cmd/search/?key-word=(.*) %{HTTP_REFERER}cmd/search/key-word/$1
```

But this not working. The new URL ever is:
localhost/bruc/sandbox/electrolux/trunk/cmd/search/?key-word=asdf

But it should be: localhost/bruc/sandbox/electrolux/trunk/cmd/search/key-word/asdf

So, I redirect this correct URL to: localhost/bruc/sandbox/electrolux/trunk/?cmd=search&key-word=asdf

But not working fine! Try, my approach here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/word/([^/]*)$ /?cmd=$1&word=$2 [L]`. I believe that will accomplish your goal.

Comment: You forgot about `cmd=search`

Comment: @Deefour Good catch, modified.

Comment: The only other thing i'd do is swap the `*` for `+`, a path like `//word/` would be a weird match

Comment: oh, and I'd throw `/?` on the end since he requested  `search/word/asdf/` :)

Comment: Not working. My real URL is http://localhost/bruc/sandbox/electrolux/trunk/search/?word=asdf

Comment: @MayW. What is it redirecting to, or is it not redirecting at all? This assumes that you are passing a `cmd` parameter. If you want this to always be cmd=search then change `$1` to `search`. But dealing with absolutes like that seems a bit silly to me.

Comment: The HTTP return is The requested URL /bruc/sandbox/electrolux/trunk/search/ was not found on this server.

Comment: @MayW. That error tells me that its not necessarily the rewrite that is failing. It sounds like it isn't finding `search` at all. Does your current url, `localhost/bruc/sandbox/electrolux/trunk/search/?word=asdf` work as expected?

Comment: No, because the cmd parameter is not being found, I believe.

Comment: @MayW. are you positive that the path to `search` is 100% correct?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/word/(.*)$ /?cmd=search&word=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /?cmd=$1&word=$2 [L]
```

There are three parts to this:

1. RewriteRule specifies that this is a rule for rewriting (as opposed to a condition or some other directive). The command is to rewrite part 2 into part 3.
2. This part is a regex, and the rule will be run only if the URL matches this regex. In this case, it says - look for the beginning of the string, then a bunch of non-slash characters, then a slash, then another bunch of non-slash characters. then again bunch of non-slash characters, then a slash, then another bunch of non-slash characters. The parentheses mean the parts within the parentheses will be stored for future reference.
3. Finally, this part says to rewrite the given URL in this format. $1 and $2 refer to the parts that were captured and stored.

Comment: This isn't right; it This might match `/search/asdf`, but does not match `/search/word/asdf/`